# cross-shaped armature with pushable center

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

I should like to create a cross-shaped armature where I can push the center while the outer points stay in their place.

How would I best go about that?

One idea that crossed my mind was that if we can use the Inverse Kinematics constraint to build something like this:

[image: animation of inverse kinematics constraint]

Then perhaps there is a way to build something like that?

[image: illustration of one idea]

When I try, though, I fail because setting the bone with the IK constraint as parent of the second middle bone will detach the middle bone from the bottom bone. When I manuall re-attach it (parent with "keep offset"), I get this:

[image: animation of failed attempt]

Which moves the bottom bone rather than rotate it.

I'd appreciate your help with this.